# Getting next lat,lon on OL Map 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have the following 2 points on the map: point A lat1 / long1 and point B lat2 / long2 in OL map  I have distance, arrived_time, speed.

With these data how can I get a estimated latitude, longitude  to the next point on 10,20,30 and 40 minutes?

Having start and end point.

Comment: GIS SE site is a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234473/get-a-lonlat-point-by-distance-or-between-2-lonlat-points

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a LonLat point by distance or between 2 lonlat points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234473/get-a-lonlat-point-by-distance-or-between-2-lonlat-points)